How to revert to the old Profiler view in Android Studio?
I recently updated Android Studio to the latest version (Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2) and noticed that the Profiler chart has changed. I prefer the older Profiler view.
Is there a way to revert back to the old Profiler view?

new profiler view
